# Whats the real reason my answer was deleted?

Tags: support

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26647

> This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive.

[image: Picture of deleted answer shown as spam or rude]

There is nothing spammy or rude or abusive.  The objection "current events not allowed" doesn't stand because Gudimalla etc have been discussed.

I feel intellectually terrorized by these actions.

Comment: Your answer is purely political which is off-topic here.

Comment: I don't see "political" listed as a reason for deletion.  I only see "spam, rude, offensive".  Why are the posts about Gudimalla standing?

Comment: Political and scientific Q/A are off-topic, see [this FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/277).

Comment: Why not SAY the answer is political as the reason for deletion?  What is spam or rude or abusive about it?

Comment: Where do you see "deleted as spam or offensive"? visit the second part of [this post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1210/277) to know how spam/offensive answers are displayed.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26646/is-it-permissible-to-deny-the-authority-of-manusmriti " 0
down vote
This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details.
shareeditundeleteflag
deleted by Pandya♦ 4 hours ago"

Comment: Not DV though but the answer is Ok for History Stack Exchange and not here. Because we are in BETA phase not all the policies are clearly defined , yet still i am not in favor of it as we are required  to answer from scripture point of view.

Comment: All I want is a clear and verifiable reason for my material getting censored. the gudimalls sacrifices have been extensively discussed. @swiftpushkar

Comment: @SK That is because the answer was flagged as rude/offensive.

Comment: Who flagged it as rude/offensive? You? or algorithms?  If humans did it, it makes no sense as there is nothing rude.  Humans may find the content offensive because of their prejudices - but thats not my problem.

Comment: @SK It was not deleted for being rude.  An ordinary user (not a mod) flagged it for being rude, but that's not why it was deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a difference between not answering & being rude. I had read your answer which although not answering the question at all but **it was not at all spam, rude or offensive in any way.** After looking at the posts of past trolls it is ludicrous to see your answer being labelled as Spam, abusive etc. 

I personally believe it was not a right decision to label your answer such. The answer could have simply been deleted but the way it has been declared rude,spam etc is not justifiable.

Comment: See the reason why it is shown as rude/spam. It was not deleted by moderator as spam/rude. It was a normal deletion  Some user flagged as rude.

Comment: @SK You can select Pandya's answer. That is more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

As I pointed in comments, your answer is purely political and doesn't address the question. Read the question again:

> My question has more to do with authority of Manusmriti than its acceptance in society. Can a normal follower of one of the above mentioned schools of Hinduism do away with Manusmriti by denying it while still following the other dharmic philosophies?

Political and scientific Q/A is off-topic here. See the [FAQ](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/277). So, your answer is  deleted for being off-opic and not answering the question.

It was not deleted (by moderator) as rude/offensive but was flagged (by user) as rude/offensive and that's why it was showing like "marked as rude/offensive" [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

To correct it, the rude/offensive falg is cleared from your answer and now you may check no such rude mark should be showing.